# Does Cursor has standalone data or it is only a pointer to the data?

Tags: java, android, gmail, cursor, duplicates

I get all the emails present in the Gmail client:

```
final Cursor messages = getContentResolver().query(
          Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/" + mailAddress + "/"
                     + String.valueOf(conversationId) + "/messages"), null, null, null,
                     null);
```

There is an issue... Sometimes, when Gmail client try to see if a new email arrived, and I,m reading in the meanwhile the above cursor, Gmail crash with "IndexOutOfBoundException". This happens once over a hundred of times... in 1% of the times, moreabout.

**First question:** I will try to duplicate the messages Cursor into a new Cursor, called copyCursur.

I don't know if this solution is right: for example, when i call

```
messages.moveToLast();
```

- A. does it read directly from "content://gmail-ls/conversations/"
- B. or messages is a COPY itselt of the data conteined in "content://gmail-ls/conversations/"?

because if A, maybe my solution colud be winning. Otherwise, if B, my solution is surely wrong.

**Second question**: how to duplicate a Cursor?
Is it right, if I do:

```
Cursor copyMessages = new Cursor();
copyMessages = messages;
```

or in this way I've only that copyMessages is a "pointer" to messages?

Thanx very much!

Comment: Can you just catch the "IndexOutOfBoundException" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pointer.
If you want to iterate over cached data, use ContentQueryMap class.